# Sorting one array based on the array.sort() of a different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

- From an array that is created based on a CSV file, I sort index 0.
  var headerArray = allText[0].split(",").sort()
- I need to reorder all subsequent indices of allText to match that of headerArray in order to map an object correctly.

The code below has two functions. The first function is to create the object. The second function is to validate headers, as well as create an array of strings that will be used in the first function to map values to the object properties (arrOfIndices).

```
//Global variable
var arrOfIndices;

function createFileObjects(allText) {

    validateHeaders(allText[0]);

    var fileMap = {}

    for(var i = 1; i < allText.length; i++) {

            var currentParams = allText[i].split(",");
            for (var j = 0; j < arrOfIndices.length; j++) {
                fileMap[arrOfIndices[j]] = currentParams[j];
            }
    }

}

function validateHeaders(headerString) {
    var headerPermutations = function (sealPerms, appNamePerms, entityIdPerms, entityNamePerms, entityTypePerms, envPerms, logIdPerms, sidPerms, userNamePerms, userStatusPerms, entlNamePerms, entlDescPerms, fidOwnerSidPerms, fidOwnerNamePerms, lmSidPerms, lmNamePerms) {
        this.sealPerms = sealPerms;
        this.appNamePerms = appNamePerms;
        this.entityIdPerms = entityIdPerms;
        this.entityNamePerms = entityNamePerms;
        this.entityTypePerms = entityTypePerms;
        this.envPerms = envPerms;
        this.logIdPerms = logIdPerms;
        this.sidPerms = sidPerms;
        this.userNamePerms = userNamePerms;
        this.userStatusPerms = userStatusPerms;
        this.entlNamePerms = entlNamePerms;
        this.entlDescPerms = entlDescPerms;
        this.fidOwnerSidPerms = fidOwnerSidPerms;
        this.fidOwnerNamePerms = fidOwnerNamePerms;
        this.lmSidPerms = lmSidPerms;
        this.lmNamePerms = lmNamePerms;
    }


    var seal = ['seal', 'id', 'seel', 'identification', 'app', 'application', 'identifier'];
    var appName = ['app', 'application', 'appl', 'applic', 'name', 'nm'];
    var entId = ['entity', 'ent', 'id', 'identifier'];
    var entName = ['entity', 'ent', 'name'];
    var entType = ['entity', 'ent', 'type'];
    var env = ['env', 'environment'];
    var logId = ['log', 'login', 'id', 'identifier'];
    var sid = ['sid', 'standard', 'id'];
    var userName = ['username', 'user', 'name', 'employee'];
    var userStat = ['status', 'user', 'employee', 'activity', 'active'];
    var entlName = ['entitlement', 'entl', 'name'];
    var entlDesc = ['entitlement', 'entl', 'description', 'desc'];
    var fidSid = ['fid', 'owner', 'sid', 'functional', 'id', 'standard'];
    var fidName = ['fid', 'owner', 'function', 'id', 'name'];
    var lmSid = ['lm', 'line', 'manager', 'sid', 'standard', 'id', 'identifier'];
    var lmName = ['lm', 'line', 'manager', 'name'];

    arrOfPermutations.push(seal, appName, entId, entName, entType, env, logId, sid, userName, userStat, entlName, entlDesc, fidSid, fidName, lmSid, lmName);
    var arrOfBools = [];
    var sortedArr = string.split(",").sort;    


    for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arrOfPermutations.length; j++) {
            var booleanTest = match(sortedArr[i], arrOfPermutations[j]);
            if (booleanTest) {
                switch (j) {
                    case 0: arrOfIndices.push("sealId");
                    break;

                    case 1: arrOfIndices.push("applicationNameInSeal");
                    break;

                    case 2: arrOfIndices.push("entityId");
                    break;

                    case 3: arrOfIndices.push("entityName");
                    break;

                    case 4: arrOfIndices.push("entityType");
                    break;

                    case 5: arrOfIndices.push("environment");
                    break;

                    case 6: arrOfIndices.push("loginId");
                    break;

                    case 7: arrOfIndices.push("userSid");
                    break;

                    case 8: arrOfIndices.push("userName");
                    break;

                    case 9: arrOfIndices.push("userStatus");
                    break;

                    case 10: arrOfIndices.push("userType");
                    break;

                    case 11: arrOfIndices.push("entitlementName");
                    break;

                    case 12: arrOfIndices.push("entitlementDesc");
                    break;

                    case 13: arrOfIndices.push("fidOwnerSid");
                    break;

                    case 14: arrOfIndices.push("fidOwnerName");
                    break;

                    case 15: arrOfIndices.push("lmSid");
                    break;

                    case 16: arrOfIndices.push("lmName");
                    break;
                }

                arrOfBools.push(true);
            }
        }

    }

    if (arrOfBools.length == sortedArr.length) {
        //return arrOfIndices
        return "File Format Correct";
    } else { return "File Format Incorrect";}
}
```

Expected result is that the object is mapped correctly based on the sorted headerArray.

Comment: Please remove the "var" inside "function validateHeaders(var headerString)". And try to simplify your question. Giving sample input and expected output could help understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was curious, I figured out an answer. (Maybe it can help someone else?)

```
for (var i = 0; i < originalArr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < sortedArr.length; j++) {
            if (originalArr[i] == sortedArr[j]) {
                arrOfIndexes.push(j);
            }

        }
    }

    var fileMap = {}
    var currentSorted = [];

    for (k = 0; k < allText.length; k++) {
            currentSorted.push(' ');
        }

    for (var i = 1; i < allText.length; i++) {
        var currentParams = allText[i].split(",");
        for (var j = 0; j < currentParams.length; j++) {

            currentSorted[arrOfIndexes[j]] = currentParams[j];

        }
        allTextSorted.push(currentSorted.join());
    }
```